# Algebraic language of fundamental results in operator algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, baer-rings

Ignoring topological structures of von Neumann algebras, the larger category of Baer $*$-rings was emerged.  In the unique text written by  Sterling K. Berberian ([1](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540057512)), some concepts and results in von Neumann algebras are algebraically given  so that they  extend to Baer *-rings.

Recently, in two successful attempts ([2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0024379519303696)),   fundamental decomposition theorems of Wold, Halmos-Wallen and, Nagy-Fiaos-Langer   have been  algebraically proved so that one may conclude them in  Baer *-rings.

Q. List any fundamental result in von Neumann algebras that can be stated algebraically. They can be reassessed to see whether they can proved  algebraically!

Example. Putnam-Fuglede theorem.